# Not able to write to JSON files using python correctly

Tags: python, json, discord.py, minecraft

So I have a discord bot which saved co-ordinates of some places in minecraft. But while saving the co-ordinates, I am not able to write to JSON file properly. It writes perfectly fine when i save the first time but when i run it again it gives me error.

Code:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["sc"])
async def save_cords(ctx, name,*, cords):
    uploader = ctx.author

    data = {"Uploader":f"{uploader}","Cords":f"{cords}","Name":f"{name}"}

    with open(f"test.json","a") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
        
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully saved cords. | Name: {name} | Cords: {cords}")
```

JSON file when written once:

```json
{
    "Uploader": "SastaSushi#6366",
    "Cords": "-88 0 -110",
    "Name": "cords"
}
```

JSON file when written again:

```json
{
    "Uploader": "SastaSushi#6366",
    "Cords": "-88 0 -110",
    "Name": "cords"
}{
    "Uploader": "SastaSushi#6366",
    "Cords": "-70 0 900",
    "Name": "village"
}
```

Here's the error when written the second time:

[image]

I want to make sure it writes in a manner where there is no error and I can read the data when wanted.

Comment: As you noted, it doesn't make much sense to append to a `json` file. I'd suggest reading in the value, updating it, then writing back to file.

Comment: Well you're appending a json to a json. You don't want to do that, you want to update the json. What you should do is load the json as a python dict, then update it with new data, then dump the dict as json and save it again.

Comment: can you please give me the code for it, I am not able to figure out how to load the data and all. I saw some tutorials but I couldnt understand, it would be very kind of you if you share the code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, someone had posted an answer to this question but had deleted it, and it worked!
So this is the code now:

````py
@client.command(aliases = ["sc"])
async def save_cords(ctx, name, *, cords):
    uploader = ctx.author

    try:
        with open("Data\\file.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = []

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = [data]

    data.append({"Uploader": f"{uploader}", "Cords": f"{cords}", "Name": f"{name}"})

    with open("Data\\file.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send(f"Successfully saved cords. | Name: {name} | Cords: {cords}")```
````

Answer (score 1):

So, the way u written is ultimately wrong the correct way is :

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["sc"])
async def save_cords(ctx, name,*, cords):
    uploader = ctx.author
    with open("test.json",r) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    nd = {}
    nd["uploader"] = uploader
    nd["Cords"] = cords
    nd["Name"] = name

    with open(f"test.json","a") as f:
        json.dump(nd, f, indent=4)
        
    await ctx.send(f"Successfully saved cords. | Name: {name} | Cords: {cords}")
```

Try This if it doesnt work reply me with error

Comment: Thank you but someone else had already answered it and it answered my question but unfortunately they deleted it so i posted the answer.